# 'café' pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I've found recently a second variant of pronunciation of 'cafe' word: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cafe.

The usual one is /ˈkafeɪ/ ˈkæ-'fay

But the OD link gives this too: /ˈkafi/ ˈkæ-fee

I have heard this second pronunciation before on BBC. I'm eager to know if it's formal/informal version? Who and when say that?

Comment: I live in the US. I have never heard the second pronunciation, ever, until this moment. I'm aware that the stressed syllable [varies](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cafe). The pronunciation you link to is uncommon in American English.

Comment: @medica: that seems to be right. Oxford doesn't list it in their American English dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cafe

Comment: I'm British, and I've never heard the second variant!

Comment: It should be noted that the word is often mispronounced intentionally by some people.  It's a fun word to play games with.

Comment: Pavel: I've edited to include content fro OD. Please check to make sure I've preserved your intent. Have you really heard this second pronunciation previous to now on the BBC?

Comment: Mitch, thank you. Yes, I've heard it on the BBC recently and that's when I got interested in the origin of this pronunciation. Up to now 3 people from the uk have said they had never heard /ˈkafi/

Comment: I am welsh. Yes the second one is pretty much standard haaha.

Comment: I'm Welsh as well, and I've never heard the *kafi* form in English (versus the Welsh word, which is indeed *caffi*). I've heard northern English people saying *kaff* to refer to greasy spoon roadside sausage-and-tea mongers, but never *kafi*.

Answer (score 2):

Being French-speaking I can tell you the second pronunciation is the French one. When anglophone people say French words they always elongate the non-native vowels or even introduce diphthongs. That's quite understandable obviously. French from France tend to shorten vowels and eliminate diphthongs, but not French from Québec. We might even add them too! I could be more chatty about this but I'll leave it at that...

Comment: Surely French speakers say /kafe/, not /ˈkafi/?

Answer (score 1):

The standard American pronunciation stresses the final syllable  /kæˈfeɪ/, whereas many speakers of “Insular English” (that is, English from the British Isles) move the stress to the first syllable as is their wont in borrowings from Romance that are not normally stressed initially.  This movement of the primary stress in the word also somewhat reduces and shortens the diphthong at the end.